# How do i nest another cmdlet in foreach loop in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

For each userID I want to get the date created for that user.

This is what I use for single user and this works.

`(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId "00444a60-3468-48e7-97d7-69f08aac346d").Get_Item("createdDateTime")`

But I want a loop. I tried below

```
Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | ForEach-Object{
    $_.ObjectId
    $_.UserPrincipalName
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CreatedDateTime" -Value (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")
}
```

But then I'm asked to put a *value* (which I don't want) and when I do so I get an error *-Value : The term '-Value' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet[...]*

I also tried this

```
Get-AzureADUser -All:$true |
    ForEach-Object {
        $UserObjectID = $_
           ForEach-Object{
               [PSCustomObject]@{
                    UserObjectID = $_.ObjectId
                    UserUserPrincipalName = $_.UserPrincipalName
                    UserDisplayName       = $_.DisplayName
                    createdDateTime = $_.createdDateTime
        }
    }
}
```

But here in result last column is empty which is understandable, because this command is not part of *Get-AzureADUser* cmdlet.

I tried some more but also without a success.
After I get this I also want to add +60 days to the *createdDateTime* but here I have no clue even how to start.

Please advise how to correct the script and add 60 days to the result.

EDIT:

I tried now this

```
Get-AzureADUser -All:$true |
    ForEach-Object {
        $UserObjectID = $_
    ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserObjectID          = $_.ObjectId
                    UserUserPrincipalName = $_.UserPrincipalName
                    UserDisplayName       = $_.DisplayName
                    DateCreated = $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CreatedDateTime" -Value (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")

        }
    }
}
```

But the DateCreated column is still empty

Comment: Remove the line break before `-Value`

Comment: I still dont get the date. This is the output:
`01663a10-9434-48e7-97d7-62f03cca236d
email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a loop construct here, you can get the desired output with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All |Select ObjectId,UserPrincipalName,@{Name='CreationDate'; Expression={(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")}}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I got an error at first but I amended it to `-All:$true` and I got the desired output. By chance do you know how to add +60 days to the date? Sth with `.AddDays(60)`?

Comment: @Jaxer `(Get-Date).AddDays(60)` will give you the datetime value representing exactly 60 * 24 hours from now

Comment: Yes, but I mean how to add 60 days to the `CreationDate` from the above line?

Comment: @Jaxer That depends on whether the value is a `[DateTime]` or a string. Give `@{...;Expression={(...).Get_Item("createdDateTime").AddDays(60)}}` a try?

Comment: Tried this `Expression={(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime").AddDays(60)}}` Column CreationDate is empty - guessing is a string. Any possible conversion?

Comment: @Jaxer [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) can do that for you. Please share an example date string if you want help figuring out the correct format

Comment: So the string is sth like `19.10.2020 13:55:29` and the variableI want to convert is createdDataTime from expression`Expression={(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")}` I have to do sth wrong, because I get blank data column all the time